# Proving $(x - y) - (z - w) = (x + w) - y - z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is
$$(x - y) - (z - w) = (x + w) - y - z$$

I got this far
$$(x - y) - (z - w) = (x - w) - y - z$$
but then I got stuck so I came here.

I need help in getting
$$(x - y) - (z - w) = (x + w) - y - z$$

Comment: Show us how you got there so we can hep you see your mistake.  What axioms are available to you?

Comment: (x - y)  - (z - w) = (x + (-y)) - (z - w) = (x - z) + ((-y) - w) = (x - z) + ((-y) + (-w)) i will comment the rest of the steps

Comment: = (x - z) + ((-w) + (-y)) = (x + (-z)) - (w + (-y)) = (x - w) + (-z)) + (-y)) = (x - w) - (y - z)

Comment: The axioms available to me are the axioms about addition and multiplication.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your work, rather than placing this information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appart from two extra closing parenthesis, you made four mistakes in the calculations shown in your comments:
$$(x - y) - (z - w)\ne(x - z) + ((-y) - w)$$
$$(x - z) + ((-w) + (-y)) \ne((x + (-z)) - (w + (-y))$$
$$(x + (-z)) - (w + (-y))\ne(x - w) + (-z)) + (-y))\text{ or rather }(x - w) + (-z) + (-y)$$
$$(x - w) + (-z) + (-y)\ne(x - w) - (y - z)$$
A correct calculation in the same style would be (using that addition is associative and commutative):
$$\begin{align}(x - y) - (z - w)&=(x-y) - (z+(-w))\\
&=(x-y)+(-z)+(-(-w))\\
&=x+(-y)+(-z)+w\\
&=x+w+(-y)+(-z)\\
&=x+w-y-z.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x-y)-(z-w)=x-y-z+w$